# Get data from 3 different websites synchronously using RxJava

Tags: java, android, rx-java

I'm very new to RxJava, and I want to get content from 3 different webpages synchronously. How do I go about doing this?

Comment: Do you ask for an operator or do you ask how to make reactive network calls?

Comment: I know how to make reactive network calls. I want to know how I can either chain 3 of them and call them asynchronously or call them synchronously without chaining.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `concat` to make the calls happen in sequence:

```
Observable call1 = ...
Observable call2 = ...
Observable call3 = ...

Observable.concat(call1, call2, call3).subscribe(...);
```

You can use `toBlocking` to make the reception synchronous:

```
Observable.concat(call1, call2, call3).toBlocking().forEach(...);
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you want to achieve parallel execution of your observables, you can do this by using combineLastest operator. In short, you should create 3 observables and merge their results via combineLastest. In this case subscribe will be triggered once each observable emits something.

For further information, please see:
http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/combinelatest.htm